Sed to delete multiple lines starting with match of pattern1 then potentially multiple matches of pattern2 (greedy)
I want to use Sed to delete blocks of lines form a file, when first line matches pattern1 then continue deleting next lines until does NOT match pattern2 (or EOF), where pattern1 and pattern2 may or may not have overlap.
For example, with this input:
one
two
six
two
two
three
three
three
four
five
two

if pattern1=/two/ and pattern2=/three/, it should return:
one
six
four
five

I have tried sed /two/,/three/d but it is not 'greedy' enough. And some solutions may not handle EOF properly.

I suggest to switch to awk or perl.

You're getting answers that'd do different things given input other than the 1 sunny-day case you've shown in your question, e.g. if a second block of two...three appeared later in the file or a two without a three or vice-versa or non-threes between a two and a three, etc.

why is six in the output?

sed is great for doing s/old/new/ on individual input strings but for anything else just use awk (the other mandatory POSIX text processing tool available on all UNIX-like machines) for some combination of clarity, simplicity, robustness, portability, maintainability, etc.
There are a few different things your requirements might mean, this implements one possibility using any awk:
$ awk '/two/{f=1; next} f && !/three/{f=0} !f' file
one
six
four
five


My understanding of OP's requirements:

there are two input patterns (eg, pattern1=two, pattern2=three)
delete a line if the first field matches pattern1
if a line was deleted due to matching pattern1 then continue deleting follow-on lines as long as the first field matches pattern2

Adding some more data to OP's sample:
$ cat sample.dat
one     # KEEP #1
three   # KEEP #2
two     # delete
six     # KEEP #3
two     # delete
two     # delete
three   # delete
three   # delete
three   # delete
four    # KEEP #4
five    # KEEP #5
two     # delete
three   # delete
six     # KEEP #6
three   # KEEP #7

NOTE: file does contain comments (added to highlight how each line will be processed)
One awk idea:
awk -v ptn1="two" -v ptn2="three" '    # pass patterns as awk variables "ptn1" and "ptn2"
$1 == ptn1         { skip=1; next }    # if 1st field matches ptn1 then set flag and go to next line of input
skip && $1 == ptn2 { next }            # if flag set (==1) and 1st field matches ptn2 then go to next line of input else ...
                   { skip=0; print }   # clear flag and print current line
' sample.dat

This generates:
one     # KEEP #1
three   # KEEP #2
six     # KEEP #3
four    # KEEP #4
five    # KEEP #5
six     # KEEP #6
three   # KEEP #7

If I edit the input file and remove all of my comments this will generate the same output (sans comments) since the awk script is  only interested in comparing the 1st field ($1):
one
three
six 
four    
five    
six 
three


This is the correct understanding of my question. Thanks for the answer. It worked. Sorry for not being sufficently clear in my examples.

example using gnu awk (using your input) may suffice.
awk '/two/{ two=1;next } two && !/three/{print} !two' input
one
six
four
five


This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -n '/two/{:a;n;/two\|three/ba};p' file

This is a filter operation so use the -n option.
Focus on lines containing two; if the subsequent lines contain either two or three, discard them, otherwise print them.
On reflection, it seems the OP wants to remove lines between overlapping patterns of two and three but only delete pattern two if these are successive:
sed -nE ':a;/two/{
           :b;n;:c;$ba;N;/(two|three)$/!bc
           /two$/{s/(.*)\n.*/\1/p;bb}
           :d;n;/three/bd;ba
          };p' file


I don't think this works because I also want to delete lines between pattern1 and pattern2 that don't match either pattern.

@DougCube perhaps you could improve your example, see edit
